# Check whether value exists in SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have produced a small program that uses a database created in MS Access. To learn something new, I decided to improve it by migrating the DB to SQL Server.

While working with Access DB in C#, I have used this code to check if the value exists in particular column of particular table:

```
//if the scanned tag already exists in the Student table...
var foundID = autoRegDataSet.Student.Select("TagID = '" + tagNo + "'");
if (foundID.Length != 0)
//do something
```

After changing to SQL Server, this piece of code returns "null" result, despite the fact, that the value I'm looking for DOES exists in `Student` table (after execution, value 4820427 should be assigned to `foundID`)

I'm totally new to SQL Server (and still quite new to programming). What is the proper way to check if the value exists in the table?

Comment: are you using Entity framework?

Comment: It *looks* like you're loading things into a `DataSet` and testing in local memory - surely it won't matter where the data came from, if the schema is the same? But also: *why* would you load it into a `DataSet` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell To be honest, I thought that this is how it should be done... Please correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @sa1986 Entity framework? Sorry but I not sure what you are asking

Comment: @jaspernorth , sa1986 is trying to understand what framework, if any, you have used to contruct your classes/model layer.
For that matter, could you post the `Select` method of your `Student` class ?

Comment: @SimonRapilly "Student" is a table of a database I have created in Access and exported to SQL server. There is no Select method for Student table. To create the program I use VS 2010.

Comment: @jaspernorth, I'm struggling to see how you exported this to sql server? I would advise you on moving the DB to sql server, and then you can create some procedures from that. Within SQL alone you can do many things, you can SELECT * FROM student, then rather than your code above you can even use the "Exists" keyword within SQL and force SQL to do your validation for you. If you want to use SQL rather than access (which I would), then use SQL to its potential, look up entity framework, go through a few tutorials with example databases, learn create update insert delete functions.

Comment: @jaspernorth , sorry lost myself a bit there for a second, did you used [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04y282hb(v=vs.100).aspx) to connect your Access db the first time ? Also what method to migrate from Access to SQL Server have you used ? And have you check if the migration worked properly with SQL Server Management Studio (by doing simple selects on the Student table) ?

Comment: @PhilipGullick To export to SQL server I have done the following:
1) I used export wizard included with SQL Server to export DB
2) created new DataSet to include new connection string
3) replaced OleDb namespace and references with SQLClient

Comment: When you populate the Dataset "autoRegDataSet", did you set the Table name manually that is "Student"? if not and Dataset is populated correctly you can try with autoRegDataSet.Tables[0].Select("TagID = '" + tagNo + "'");

if there is only one table in the Data set.
if more then one table in there you can check by changing the index number of the Table.

Comment: @SimonRapilly In both cases I have used VS DataSource Wizard to connect the DB. I have produced 2 pretty complicated queries, and they give me expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of unclear things in the question, but I suspect the biggest question here is whether `TagID` is a numeric type vs a string type. But there's also the big question of why it is going into a data-set.

But; getting back to the actual question - checking if a value exists; I would do something like (using [dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) to make correct parameterization simple):

```
// where tagNo is a local variable...
int? id = connection.Query<int?>(
    "select Id from Student where TagID=@tagNo", new { tagNo }
).FirstOrDefault();
if(id == null) {
    // doesn't exist
} else {
    // exists, plus you now know the id - it is: id.Value
}
```

But ultimately, if your original code worked in a `DataSet`, it should *continue* working - if it isn't, I suspect you have simply messed up the schema (maybe a column that was `string` is now `int` or similar).

Comment: This is helpfull, thanks! So you are saying that I don't really need to use DataSet when working with SQL DB in Visual Studio? And yes, I have altered some columns inside SQL Management Studio

Comment: @jaspernorth yes, loading everything into a `DataSet` shouldn't be something you do "just because". Unfortunately, it tends to be what a lot of walkthrough examples do *because it is quick and easy*, and ideal for examples. The number of times I have used `DataSet` in real code is *very* small. Some people swear by them, of course.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me then how should I properly add a SQL database as data source to VS project? I will be really gratefull

Comment: @jaspernorth you *don't need to*; you just use it via `SqlConnection`, providing the correct connection-string.#

Comment: Really?! I did not know. But I also take advantage of having a DataSet by displaying data in DGV (it requires a DataSet binding source in order to display data). Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: You Sir are my savior again! Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: @jaspernorth `DataGridView` will bind perfectly happily to just a `List<SomeType>`. You don't have to use `DataTable` etc. You *can*, of course - but you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

How did you convert your Access DB to MSSQL ?

CHeck what is the dataType of TagID, it might be integer,
then it will be useful to drop the '' quotes.

`object foundID = autoRegDataSet.Student.Select("TagID = " + tagNo);`

Cheers.